# Generating instances of duplicate files

Tags: python, file, exception

I'm trying to edit a script I've previously written to generate .lab files (or basically txt files with a .lab extension) as part of a project I'm currently working on.  Specifically, what I'm currently working on is to edit the script such that it will be able to handle duplicate filenames.  Example: if a file named `filename` already exists, instead of appending or overwriting the existing file, it would instead create a new file named `filename_1`.

The script is written as shown below:

```
for line in reader:
        utterance = line[4]
        path = line[1].split("/")
        folder_name = path[len(path) - 2]
        file_name = path[len(path) - 1].split(".")[0]
        duplicate_num = 0

        # Generate the .lab file
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(truncated_audio_dir + "/" + folder_name + "/" + file_name + "_cut.lab"):
                new_file_name = file_name + "_" + str(duplicate_num)
                while os.path.isfile(truncated_audio_dir + "/" + folder_name + "/" + new_file_name + "_cut.lab"):
                    duplicate_num += 1
                    new_file_name = file_name + "_" + str(duplicate_num)
                    print("New File Name: ", new_file_name)

                outfile = open(truncated_audio_dir + "/" + folder_name + "/" + file_name + "_cut.lab", "a")
                outfile.write(utterance)
                outfile.close()
                
            elif not os.path.isfile(truncated_audio_dir + "/" + folder_name + "/" + file_name + "_cut.lab"):
                print("Is File")
                outfile = open(truncated_audio_dir + "/" + folder_name + "/" + file_name + "_cut.lab", "a")
                outfile.write(utterance)
                outfile.close()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(truncated_audio_dir + "/" + folder_name + "/" + file_name + "_cut.lab" + " not found")
            continue
```

The issue is that when I try and run the script, the issues I'd been experiencing beforehand still seem to persist.  Particularly, the case I'd written to handle duplicates does not seem to trigger at all, instead the program keeps throwing `FileNotFoundError` exceptions (which I'd originally written to handle the case if there was a directory that didn't exist).  I'm suspecting that the `FileNotFoundError` exception handling I'd originally written is causing the issue, but maybe there may be something else that I may not be aware of.  Any help would be gladly appreciated.

(the above code is a majority of the script, but not the complete script; I imported `sys`, `csv`, and `os` and `reader` refers to a csv that I am reading from)

Comment: Better to use os.path.join to construct paths than to do so via string concatenation.

Comment: Here's example code to generate a unique filename with counter, as needed: https://snipplr.com/view/41834/unique-file-name-counter

Comment: It looks like the variable `new_file_name` goes nowhere. You don't use it after it was created.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it was going to be as simple a mistake as this. That fixed my issue, thanks